# Calling an ActionResult from an OnChange event [MVC4]

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This is something that I know can be done with coding a function in JQuery or Javascript, but it seems like the sort of thing that **should** be possible very succinctly by just adding the right string into the HtmlAttributes of an HtmlHelper, given how slick MVC4 is.

I'm probably missing something really simple, so please forgive me if I'm asking the obvious.

Take this situation:

1. You have a working MVC4 application which you want to modify as follows
2. You want to call an ActionResult in a Controller to modify the contents of a page in response to the user having changed the value of a checkbox.
3. The checkbox is inside a form, but you don't want to submit the form because that will cause other validations to take place which are better left until the user is ready to submit
4. You want to pass the model to the ActionResult, just the same as would have happened with a submit
5. The page changes cannot be done client-side because a new model will be built

I have tried putting a $.Post into the HtmlAttributes of the checkbox, which directs control to the ActionResult just fine, but I can't work out how to pass the model without coding a function.  Considering everything else about MVC is set up to pass models around in very intuitive ways, it strikes me that there must be a way of doing this cleanly... is there?

Many thanks

Comment: How much of the initial page changes? Is it something you can do by just getting an HTML snippet from a partial view and replacing/appending the results into the current page?

Comment: Hi ic, well yes that might be a way of updating the page, but am I not still left with the problem of how to activate the actionresult that would do this?  The actionresult needs to examine the current state of the model in order to decide what action to take...

Comment: Can't you just do something like `$.post('@Url.Action("Bar", "Foo")', $('#myForm').serialize(), function(data) { /*do something with the response*/ });`? MVC should recognize the incoming JSON and populate your model from it (I think)

Comment: Nice one, yes, that'll do, many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `serialize()` the form and send the data; the MVC model binder should do the rest:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("Bar", "Foo")', 
    $('#myForm').serialize(), 
    function(data) { /*do something with the response*/ });
```